# Parse Server migrate current files from GridFS to S3

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

In my parse server project, we saved all files locally with GridFS in the database. Over time the database is growing fast and needs a lot of space. I analyzed this and saw that files use a lot of space.

I would like to migrate all current files which are saved currently in GridFS to AWS S3 via S3 file adapter.

Is there any way or plan for how to do that? Is there maybe some sample code or steps on how I can do that without creating data inconsistency.

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. You will have to create a script to read the files from gridfs and upload them to aws s3. Once it is done, you will need to change your parse server configuration to use the aws s3 adapter.

Comment: There is this public repository that we've created a while back ago: https://github.com/back4app/migrate-mongodb-files-to-s3. You can try to use it or at least get some inspiration. Use it on your own risk :)